# Send GCP project performance report to alternate email id

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Is there an option to send Performance Summary to one of the emails in Notification Channels (I get alerts in notification-channel-email but not Performace Summary)

In my current config, GCP sends this report only to email id associated with the gcp-project. What setting should I change so it goes to an email in notification-channel-email?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could use this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/support/notification-options#creating_channels) to add a new notification channel and then set up the way you want to receive notifications from your alerting.